# How to check who changed the user count in sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore-client

Our current Sitecore license allows 3 concurrent users. Through Boost users screen someone has increased the user count. Is there a way to find who is changing the number of users on the Boost screen and how can we lock it down? Does Sitecore maintains any audit for the same? if so where am I supposed to find it? Do I need to raise Sitecore ticket for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sitecore representative for you or your client can provide the date of occurrence. Once you have that, you can search the Sitecore log for the following lines.:

```
The maximum number of simultaneously active (logged-in) editors exceeded. The User sitecore\xxx cannot be logged in to the system. The maximum of editors allowed by license is 5.
```

or for IIS request log manually or through Application Insights(depending on your setup):

```
2023-01-13 21:20:39 xxx.xx.xx.xxx GET /api/sitecore/BoostUsers/RedirectToBoost - 80 sitecore\Admin
```